# Read a pickle with a different version of pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can't read a pickle file saved with a different version of Python pandas. I know this has been asked here before, but the solutions offered, using `pd.read_pickle("my_file.pkl")` is not working either. I think (but I am not sure) that these pickle files were created with an **newer** version of pandas than that of the machine I am working now.

Unfortunately, I am not the administrator and I cannot change the version of pandas. How can I read my files? Are they irrecoverable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need the same version (or a later one) of pandas as the one used `to_pickle`.
When pandas converts a dataframe to pickle the compress process is specific to that version.

I advise to contact your administrator and have them convert the `pickle to csv` that way you can open it with any version of pandas.

Unless the dataframe contains objects csv should be fine

Comment: Thanks. Could a newer version read an old one or it has to be exactly the same version of pandas that created it?

Comment: anytime your working at the binary level (ie pickles) you usually want the same versions

Comment: Ok. In case anyone is interested, the administrator suggested a `virtualenv`, where I was able to install a newer version of pandas. That solved it.

Answer (score 6):

Regarding your question about compatibility in the comments, per the [docs related to pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#relationship-to-other-python-modules), "The pickle serialization format is guaranteed to be backwards compatible across Python releases provided a compatible pickle protocol is chosen..." If the files were pickled with a newer protocol than you're reading with, you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 5):

For data frames that contain objects such as lists and arrays in individual cells, instead of converting to a csv file, saving as hdf worked.

#### Step 1

Load data with the newest version of python and pandas (python 3.8 and pandas 1.4.1 in my case).

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
data = pd.read_pickle('path/to/file.pkl')
```

#### Step 2

Save the loaded data as a hdf file and set pickle protocol to 4 and key to data frame

```
pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL = 4
data.to_hdf('output/folder/path/to/file.hdf', 'df')
```

#### Step 3

Load the hdf file with the older python (Python 3.7 and pandas 1.3.5 on google colab for me)

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_hdf(path)
```