# Unable to open .spydata in spyder: "Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on"

Tags: python, spyder

I am starting to use spyder, and I am having an issue in importing the data.
Yesterday, I saved all variables using 'save data' in variable explorer, generating a file called `data.spydata`. I opened a new project just to test if it was OK, and I was able to open it.
Today, I am attempting to importing all data from that `data.spydata`. Initially it complained about no pandas, and I have installed it using `pip install pandas`, and stopped complaining about. Now, the message is

> Unable to load '//data.spydata'
> The error message was: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on

The sentence appears to end without a complement, and I have no idea what it means... the variables were diverse, but mainly panda's data frame, lists and dictionaries... a request response, and json from this response...

The spyder is running in a conda environment. After the first message, I verified all packages used in the original code (pandas, request) are installed in that environment...

I appreciate any help.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This probably happened because you used two different versions of Pandas to save/load your data.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Thank you very much for taking your time  to send me the message! updating the Pandas version solved the issue!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recently encountered the same problem! Then I realized that the pandas that I generated the pkl has version 1.4.0; while the pandas that I used to extract pkl has version 1.3.0.

So what I do is to downgrade/upgrade pandas.
[This is a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68625748/attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-new-block-on-module-pandas-core-internal)

Comment: Thank you! Updating pandas solved the issue! Not sure what version I had before, but the version was 1.3.5. I updated t o1.4.0, and it solved! Just a comment/doubt... considering the mentioned here [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58822947/8939181], maybe we have no problem if we have the newest version to extract (no downgrade is needed)?

Comment: Same problem with matplotlib. Error message reads *Spyder is unable to open the file you're trying to load because matplotlib.axes.subplots is not installed.* Downgraded matplotlib from 3.7 to 3.6. Then Spyder loaded the file but threw a warning message in the console *This figure was saved with matplotlib version 3.6.2 and is unlikely to function correctly.* So then I knew which version the file was saved in. There is definitively an advantage in using conda environments...