# Python 3.8 and pickle load()

Tags: python, pandas, pickle, python-3.8

I am struggling reading a pickle file. I keep having the `EOFError: Ran out of input`
My file is definitely not empty and I am using python3.8 with pandas 1.4.4

[image]

When I try to load the file with python I get:

[image]

Note that the pickle object was saved with HIGHEST_PROTOCOL. Is there any incompatibility with 3.8 and pandas?

Comment: No, there is no incompatibility.

Comment: What version of Pandas was the pickle file generated with? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71090354/15239951

Comment: I have tried with python3.6 and python3.8 and multiple pandas versions. No success so far.