# Can't read in pickeld dataframe with either pd.read_pickle or pickle.load

Tags: pandas, pickle, attributeerror

I’m trying to read in a dataframe I pickled. It worked well untill last week, but today I got an error that says ‘ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5’.

I found this page [unsupported-pickle-protocol-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329657/python-3-7-error-unsupported-pickle-protocol-5/65318801#65318801) and downloaded pickle5, changed my read in code from pd.read_pickle to pickle.load. Then I got another error: AttributeError: Can’t get attribute ‘_unpickle_block’. So I found another page [cant-get-attribute-unpickle-block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090310/attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-unpickle-block)
and it suggested me to return to using pd.read_pickle! So I’m dead on both ends.
Can anyone help? My pickled data is [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vr7fAR9UX-Z8_P5_peb4iIqlgdFoBBKx/view?usp=share_link)
The least amount of code I used to read it in is,

```
#method 1
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_pickle('df.pkl')

#method 2
import pickle5 as pickle
with open('df.pkl', "rb") as fh:
  data = pickle.load(fh)
```

Dependencies in my virtual environment are
[dependencies](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15NoT25dQ1h8wtnLIKi4AiaeCH67Nkz2w/view?usp=share_link)
（I had intended to display this using table, but for some weird reason this markdown table is not rendering on stackoverflow）

And the screenshot of the error is [error report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krYfz.png).
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Did you try to downgrade pandas as suggested in the second link?

Comment: Hi Mortz, I just tried downgraded pandas to 1.1.5, it still doesn't work.