# Cannot open pickle file generated by snakemake pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, snakemake

I have a data analysis pipeline that consists of multiple steps. I have generated a snakemake pipeline (new for me) and the output of every task (and input of the next task) is a pickle file containing either a DataFrame or a list of DataFrames. Everything is fine except I cannot open the pickle files manually. Of note, the pipeline uses a dedicated conda environment.

```py
import _pickle
with open("testb/first/out/stacks.pkl", "rb") as f:
    data = _pickle.load(f)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on <module 'pandas._libs.internals' from 'C:\\Users\\sebde\\anaconda3\\envs\\dbm\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas\\_libs\\internals.cp39-win_amd64.pyd'
```

Python 3.10.2,
Snakemake-minimal 7.0.4 (as per documentation, I'm on Windows),
Pandas 1.4.1

Comment: The first thing that came to my mind was to check the compatibility between the pandas and the pickle, but I assume that is no issue.
The second is a recommendation, maybe you can try  convert the pickle to csv that way you can open it with any version of pandas. Unless the dataframe contains objects csv should be fine.

Comment: Some of the dataframes contain objects indeed. csv conversion is not applicable in my case.

Comment: Some googling suggests this may be due to different versions of pandas used to write and read the pickle (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70944402/unable-to-open-spydata-in-spyder-cant-get-attribute-unpickle-block-on) - could that be the case for you? Check the version of pandas inside and outside the conda env.

Comment: Items beginning with underscore are internals and not meant to be accessed. Maybe you switched to that when using Pandas `read_pickle` wasn't working? If you tried other things then they should be in the post. Did you use Pandas to pickle your objects? As others point out, use the same Pandas version to unpickle. Is this specific to snakemake being involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe, you might be better match the version of `pandas` between when saving the file and when loading the file.

I also got similar error `AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block'` like this.

```py
import joblib
import pandas as pd  # 1.4.3


df = pd.DataFrame({"a": 1, "b": 2})
joblib.dump(df, "train.dump", compress=True)

# --------------------------------

# When loading this, pandas 1.3.5 is installed.
import joblib


def load(path):
    return joblib.load(path)


train_data = load("train.dump")
```

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/work/tools/script.py", line 45, in <module>
    train_data = load("train.dump")
  File "/home/ec2-user/work/tools/script.py", line 16, in load
    return joblib.load(path)
  File "/home/ec2-user/work/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 658, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "/home/ec2-user/work/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 577, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 1213, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 1538, in load_stack_global
    self.append(self.find_class(module, name))
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 1582, in find_class
    return _getattribute(sys.modules[module], name)[0]
  File "/home/ec2-user/.pyenv/versions/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/pickle.py", line 331, in _getattribute
    raise AttributeError("Can't get attribute {!r} on {!r}"
AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on <module 'pandas._libs.internals' from '/home/ec2-user/work/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/_libs/internals.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
```

I was using `pandas` `1.3.5` when I loaded the file.
But actually, I saved a DataFrame made with `pandas` `1.4.3`, in the file "train.dump".

So I retried to exec `joblib.load` after re-installing pandas `1.4.3`.
Consequently, I could load the file "train.dump"!

Please, refer to another advice.
[AttributeError: Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71090310/attributeerror-cant-get-attribute-unpickle-block)

Answer (score 0):

One easy thing to try (but which might not work) is to use [`pickle` rather than `_pickle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19191885/10693596):

```py
# the "as" part is to avoid adjust downstream code
# but if this is not a concern a regular import is better
# (i.e. "import pickle")
import pickle as _pickle
```