# Unable to open .spydata in spyder: 'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spyder

I am having an issue when trying to import a `.spydata` file in Spyder. I created a `.spydata` file in a console using Spyder, then I opened a new console (same environment and everything) and tried to import the file.
Then Spyder throws an error:

> `'Unable to load .../.spydata'`
> `The error message was:`
> `'Object arrays cannot be loaded when allow_pickle=False'`

The `.spydata` file contains these object types: List, Set, Array, Dictionary, int, tuple, DataFrame, timedelta, timestamp.

I was able to succesfully save and import a `.spydata` file with less objects (only two cells from the original script run).

I tried opening the file in a new environment with `Numpy==1.16.1` (and `pandas==1.1` for compatibility issues) as suggested in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55890813/how-to-fix-object-arrays-cannot-be-loaded-when-allow-pickle-false-for-imdb-loa). But then I got this error message:

> `'Unable to load .../.spydata'`
> `The error message was:`
> `"Can't get attribute '_unpickle_block' on"`

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70944402/unable-to-open-spydata-in-spyder-cant-get-attribute-unpickle-block-on) the solution to that last error given by @CarlosCordoba is:

> (Spyder maintainer here) This probably happened because you used two different versions of Pandas to save/load your data.

Yes, that was the problem. I had to downgrade `pandas` to version `1.1`. And users seem to be able to fix the problem saving and loading the data with the same pandas version. Not me, I get the first error message.

```
Environment package versions:
Python   3.10.6
Anaconda 2.3.1
Spyder   5.3.2
Ipython  7.33.0
Numpy    1.23.3
Pandas   1.5.0
```

Comment: Are you using the default interpreter or a custom one? Could you provide an example code snippet to test locally?

Comment: @Daniel Althviz I'm using the default interpreter, meaning the Python interpreter is the same as Spyder's. I can't provide a example code snippet because the data is confidential. I just run the code, save the data in a .spydata file using the Variable Explorer and the try to open it back again in a new console. I edited the question to provide examples of the type of objects in the .spydata file.

Answer (score 2):

Found it!
The problem was a single `numpy.ndarray`
In my case, I just converted the `numpy.ndarray` into a `list`.
None of the other types of objects threw an error.
The `.spydata` file had basic Python structures, Pandas objects and even PuLP objects.
It is still an [open issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/11754) for Spyder.