# pickle fails to load data: TypeError: _unpickle_timestamp() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, timestamp, pickle

I have a dataset, stored in a pandas dataframe, that I have built and pickled in one environment.  The pickle file loads fine in that environment (environment 1).  However, when I try to load it in a different environment (environment 2), I get an error regarding unpickling timestamps. The error and the pickle versions are below.

The pickle versions are the same for both environments, although the build versions for the cloudpickle packages are different. Another difference is that environment 1 is python==3.10.12 and environment 2 is python==3.9.12.

I have tried installing the specific cloudpickle build, but conda fails to find a solution.  I'm hesitant to try upgrading the python version of environment 2, as getting the keras dependencies to install along with the other packages I need in that environment is ... fussy.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
runfile('D:/driver_backprop.py', wdir='D:')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\jerem\anaconda3\envs\keras\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356, in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File "d:\driver_backprop.py", line 14, in <module>
    data_df = pickle.load(f)

  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps._unpickle_timestamp

TypeError: _unpickle_timestamp() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (4 given)
```

The code I'm using to load the file:

```
import pickle
with open('data_w-solar.pickle','rb') as f:
    data_df = pickle.load(f)
    station_dict = pickle.load(f)
```

The pickle versions in environment 1 (which successfully loads):

```
(shadow) C:\Users\jerem>conda list pickle
# packages in environment at C:\Users\jerem\anaconda3\envs\shadow:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cloudpickle               2.2.1           py310haa95532_0
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
```

The pickle versions in environment 2 (which fails to load):

```
(keras) C:\Users\jerem>conda list pickle
# packages in environment at C:\Users\jerem\anaconda3\envs\keras:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
cloudpickle               2.2.1            py39haa95532_0
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be the pandas version (1.4.3 vs. 2.0.3): when I downgrade environment 1, it fails to load with the same error.  Unfortunately, upgrading pandas or python in environment 1 to match those in environment 2 fails to solve.

I also tried the solutions here but none worked:
[Read a pickle with a different version of pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58822129/read-a-pickle-with-a-different-version-of-pandas)

I think the only solution is to go through the hassle of creating a new keras environment with pandas=2.0.3+.